# How to make helper methods available in a Rails integration test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, testing

I have a helper file in `app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb` that includes a method `my_preference` which returns the preference of the currently logged in user. I would like to have access to that method in an integration test. For example, so that I can use `get user_path(my_preference)` in my tests.

In other posts I read this is possible by including `require sessions_helper` in the test file, but I still get the error `NameError: undefined local variable or method 'my_preference'`. What am I doing wrong?

```
require 'test_helper'
require 'sessions_helper'

class PreferencesTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  test "my test" do
    ...
    get user_path(my_preference)
  end

end
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your error messagae says:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method 'my_preference'
```

which means you don't have access to `my_preference` method. To make that available in your class, you have to `include` the module in your class.

You have to include your module: `SessionsHelper` in your `PreferencesTest` class.

```
include SessionsHelper
```

Then, the instance method `my_preference` will be available for you to use in your test.

So, you want to do:

```
require 'test_helper'
require 'sessions_helper'


class PreferencesTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  include SessionsHelper

  test "my test" do
    ...
    get user_path(my_preference)
  end

end
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! It now also seems to work if I leave out `require 'sessions_helper'`. Does that make sense? Is `require 'sessions_helper'` necessary?

Comment: yeah, you should not need that if its under `app/helpers` directory
let me know!

Answer (score 3):

In case someone wants to have particular helper methods available in all tests, it is possible to include helper modules in the `test_helper.rb`  file:

```
class ActiveSupport::TestCase 
 ...
 include SessionsHelper
end
```